# :app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED, ...zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/...v4/widget/SearchViewCompatIcs$MySearchView.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, sharethis

I've been working on this issues for a several hours but can't find the solution. Tried a lots of answers from stackoverflow but no luck.

What am I getting is the following gradle error while running the app:

```
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatIcs$MySearchView.class
```

Android studio throws the error when i add the dependency of **ShareThis Sdk** into the gradle. Here is the full gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'Alies'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storeFile file('path.jks')
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
    }
    //configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }
    //configurations { all*.exclude module: 'support-v4' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile project(':library-circular')
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project(':sliding_library1')
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project(':sdk')
}
```

A small help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem has been resolved. Actually there was a conflict between **`support-v4`** jar files, So I simply used the same **`support-v4.jar`** everywhere and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is in [Compile independent modules in parallel (may require larger heap size)](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/compiler-gradle-android-compiler.html). So, disabling that option and clear rebuild should fix it.

Looks like Android Build Tools for multidex *sometimes* try to include lib project in both dex files and it causes some conflict then compiled simultaneously.